# Cannot read propety of undefined - ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, undefined

Im getting this error: TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of undefined

The code is getting the object at the start and getting the unique values and counting the number of them.
Then im trying to access the object but its saying its undefined.

This is the output to the console.

```
    (3) ["Online", "Offline", "Warning"]
ServerCount.jsx:69 (3) [{…}, {…}, {…}]0: {value: "Online", count: 1}1: {value: "Offline", count: 1}2: {value: "Warning", count: 1}length: 3__proto__: Array(0)
ServerCount.jsx:76 {value: "Online", count: 1}
ServerCount.jsx:76 {value: "Offline", count: 1}
ServerCount.jsx:76 {value: "Warning", count: 1}
```

Its marking this as the error:

> 77 |     if(newArr[i].value === "Online") arr.Online = newArr[i].count

I cant seem to figure out what is the problem, is there a easy way to fix it or do I need to redesign the code?

```
    // This is the data that is getting pushed down - its working fine.


     class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      servers: [
        {
          host: "192.168.57.108",
          status: "Online",
          title: "Server",
          location: "Location"
        },
        {
          host: "192.168.57.71",
          status: "Offline",
          title: "Server",
          location: "Location"
        },
        {
          host: "192.168.57.90",
          status: "Warning",
          title: "Server",
          location: "Location"
        }
      ]
    };
    this.handleFormData = this.handleFormData.bind(this);
    this.handleStatusExtract = this.handleStatusExtract.bind(this);
    this.handleUserClick = this.handleUserClick.bind(this);
  }

  handleFormData(data) {
    let newState = this.state.servers.slice();
    newState.push(data);

    this.setState({
        servers: newState
    });
  }

  handleStatusExtract() {
    let arr = this.state.servers
    return arr.map(server => server.status);
  }

  handleUserClick(data) {
    let index = this.state.servers.findIndex(server => server.host === data)
    this.setState({
      servers: this.state.servers.filter((_, i) => i !== index)
    })
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <Default>
        <div className="upperContainer">
          <ServerCount serverCount={this.handleStatusExtract()} />
          <RequestTimer />
        </div>
        <ServerList serverList={this.state.servers} handleUserClick={this.handleUserClick}/>
        <Input handleFormData={this.handleFormData} />
      </Default>
    );
  }
}
    class ServerCount extends Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            Total: 0,
            Online: 0,
            Warning: 0,
            Offline: 0
        };

        this.compressArray = this.compressArray.bind(this);
        this.handleCountingServers = this.handleCountingServers.bind(this);
    }

    componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
        if(prevProps.serverCount !== this.props.serverCount) {
            this.handleCountingServers();
        }
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        this.handleCountingServers();
    }

    compressArray(original) {

        let compressed = [];
        let copy = original.slice(0);

        for (let i = 0; i < original.length; i++) {

            var myCount = 0;    
            for (let w = 0; w < copy.length; w++) {
                if (original[i] === copy[w]) {
                    myCount++;
                    delete copy[w];
                }
            }

            if (myCount > 0) {
                let a = {};
                a.value = original[i];
                a.count = myCount;
                compressed.push(a);
            }
        }

        return compressed;
    }

    handleCountingServers() {
        let prevArr = this.props.serverCount;
        console.log(prevArr)
        let newArr = this.compressArray(prevArr);
        console.log(newArr);
        let arr = {
            Online: 0,
            Warning: 0,
            Offline: 0
        };
        for(var i = 0; i <= newArr.length; i++) {
            console.log(newArr[i])
            if(newArr[i].value === "Online") arr.Online = newArr[i].count
            if(newArr[i].value === "Warning") arr.Warning = newArr[i].count
            if(newArr[i].value === "Offline") arr.Offline = newArr[i].count
        }
        this.setState({
            Online: arr.Online,
            Offline: arr.Offline,
            Warning: arr.Warning
        })
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <CountContainer>
                <div className="circleContainer">
                    <div className="total serverCircle">
                        {this.state.Total}
                    </div>
                    Total
                </div>
                <div className="circleContainer">
                    <div className="Online serverCircle">
                        {this.state.Online}
                    </div>
                    Online
                </div>
                <div className="circleContainer">
                    <div className="Warning serverCircle">
                        {this.state.Warning}
                    </div>
                    Warning
                </div>
                <div className="circleContainer">
                    <div className="Offline serverCircle">
                        {this.state.Offline}
                    </div>
                    Offline
                </div>
            </CountContainer>
        )
    }
}
```

Comment: You have shared only data but please share the code as well

Comment: @Think-Twice I have shared the code, its all there.

Comment: @Think-Twice or do you mean the code from the parent element?

Comment: The component code wr the error occurred but not just the If condition that doesn’t help us to help you

Comment: this line
for(var i = 0; i <= newArr.length; i++)

maybe it should be
for(var i = 0; i <newArr.length; i++)
since newArr[newArr.length] doesn't exist?

Comment: @AlexG That worked like a charm.. Do you want to set that as an answer and ill mark it as correct? And put a little explanation cause im not sure why it worked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your for loop in handleCountingServers function should be

`for (var i = 0; i < newArr.length; i++)`

Before you were accessing newArr[newArr.length].

And since array indices are from 0 to array length - 1, you were trying to access the value property of undefined.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Perfect - thanks for the help and explanation why. Makes perfect sense now.